# How is 空気を読む translated into English?

Tags: translation, word-requests, idioms

I've often seen 'read the air' (literal translation) or 'read between the lines' but is there a better rendition of this concept in English? Or does it just not exist?

Comment: "Read between the lines" = `眼【がん】光【こう】紙【し】背【はい】`.  Also related (but possibly outdated slang) - [When Japanese say KY on the Internet, what does it mean exactly?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/372/78)

Comment: Not an answer because I don't think this translation exists widely outside my own family, but my mum says "has no antennae" for 空気読めない.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think "read between the lines" accurately conveys the intended meaning of `空気{くうき}を読{よ}む`. Reading between the lines is usually if you are given a specific phrase, written or spoken, and you are expected to understand an implied, and intended, meaning that is not directly stated. Whereas reading the air, as far as I know, is about understanding a situational context, which may have no verbal component, that might ensue whether or not anyone intended it to be that way. Reading the air is much more ethereal than reading between the lines.

There is no one-to-one match in English for "reading the air", but the concept definitely exists. Never mistake not having a set phrase for not grasping a reality. People talk about that kind of thing all the time, it's just that they will have to construct descriptions from words and grammar suited to the situation, not easily refer to a preset.

If someone had no ability to read the air, I would simply say that person was "oblivious". If someone did have the ability to read the air, I would say that person was "intuitive", "perceptive", or "sensitive".

Sensitive to what? The "atmosphere", the "mood", or the "situation". Or, to be even more ethereal, I might just use "it" to encompass the things I feel I can't encompass, like when we say, "don't you get it?".

So, for situations of not successfully reading the air, I might say, "That guy is oblivious to the situation". For successful reads, "that guy really gets it." If I wanted to push someone, I might say, "dude, can't you see what's going on here?"

Other *related* phrases that might give you a sense of how English applies in similar situations are *(note these are just my own constructions, easily understood but not conventional)*:

- "Do I have to spell it out for you?"
- "There's more going on here than meets the eye."
- "Get with it."

In short, to describe reading the air in English, you'll have to successfully read the air to the point where you can apply the most suitable English phrasing.

As a last note, I think "read the air" has a high potential for transfer into English. I believe that if one person told another to "read the air", and even if they had no knowledge of the Japanese phrase, the meaning would very likely be understood. It sounds a little poetic, but well within the bounds of everyday usability.

In fact, I think I'm going to start using it in English, as I feel like it closes a lexical gap. We have the idea, but not the phrase. So if you ever hear someone in English refer to "reading the air" as a part of their discourse, you'll know where it started. `;)`.

Comment: This is an awesome answer!!! 

I totally understand the 'just because there isn't a word for it, doesn't mean it doesn't exist' sentiment since it's easy enough to just default and believe that it doesn't exist.  Random follow-up question, is there any meaning in the fact that there isn't a set-phrase for 空気を読む in English?

Comment: @ishikun: I couldn't tell you if there is meaning, but it might be an indicator of where each culture puts emphasis on collective understanding. In Japan, you could say that a context of understanding between people is thought to be more objective and separate from all participants, even though it ensues from all of them. Whereas in the west, collective understanding is assumed to be contingent on each observer's perspective, and necessarily subjective. That's just me playing armchair sociologist, though. I can't offer anything more factual.

Comment: There is totally an English equivalent though - 'read the atmosphere'.

Comment: @Sjiveru: You could say that, sure, but I definitely wouldn't go so far as to say it's particularly special or different from any other alternative option. "Read the room", "catch the mood", "feel the vibe"... etc...

Comment: Although terribly politically incorrect, someone who in Japanese I might hear described as being "KY" or who is always "KY", I often hear the same kind of person talked about as being "a bit aspergic" in English (whether they are or not). The implication being that people with Asperger's / autistic spectrum conditions are pathologically unable to "read the air".

Comment: Wow, that I've never heard that before (nor will I use it) but it's nice to know.  Is there a particular place (e.g. TV or just commonplace conversation?) that you've heard that term being used?

Comment: @Sjiveru, There is a difference between the ability to convey an idea, and a set phrase with an understood cultural weight. 空気を読む is commonly used in Japanese, "read the air" is not commonly used in English. [See this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=read+the+air%2C+read+between+the+lines&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cread%20the%20air%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cread%20between%20the%20lines%3B%2Cc0) comparing "read the air" versus a common phrase like "read between the lines". "Read the air" has insignificant usage in English.

Comment: I normally use KY or 空気読めない in Japanese where in English I would say that someone "doesn't get it", or "isn't with the program"

Comment: “To read the room.”

Answer (score 1):

Not a literal translation but “read the room” or “feel the atmosphere” have similar idiomatic usage in English.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case 空気 is similar to 雰囲気.

So 雰囲気を読む　or 場の雰囲気を読む has a pretty similar meaning to 空気を読む.

I'd translate 空気 as the "mood" or "feel", in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would most closely be something along the lines of "read the mood" in English, because it's talking about something that isn't spoken but rather felt in the way someone is talking to you. To 'read the air' could be to enter a room and immediately feel as mood difference from the people in the room, or to understand what a person is telling you at a higher level than just what words they are saying, but rather understanding what the specific person is either implying or what emotions are being felt at the time. the 'air' is seemingly not tangible just like the 'mood' of someone or multiple people, yet some people can feel when somethings off, while more clueless people can't 'read' it at all.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could [edit] your post and explain how you arrived at this, or provide reputable reference.

Answer (score 0):

Being emotionally intelligent is somewhat of a similar expression, though not exactly.