# Understanding「雰囲気で点が取れるとはなんだったのか」

Tags: meaning

A guy invited his friend 伊理戸 to hang out in his room. Unfortunately, he only wants to study for a test. So the guy thought

> 伊理戸のやつテストばっかしててつまらねー!! 雰囲気で点が取れるとはなんだったのか

I am not quite sure about the meaning of「雰囲気で点が取れるとはなんだったのか」. The translations said "so much for very little effort" but I can't see where this meaning came from. I think it means something like "What is the point of getting high marks from atmosphere"? I don't understand what 雰囲気 means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The literal translation of 雰囲気で点が取れる is indeed "can get high marks from atmosphere". Here, 雰囲気で is a slangy phrase that means something like "relying on one's guessing ability or intuition (rather than knowledge, logic or experience)". So it's a kind of test where you can guess the correct answers just by reading the questions carefully and using your common sense. If you happen to know [空気を読む](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12790/5010), this 雰囲気で is in the same vein. There is a net meme [俺たちは雰囲気で～している](https://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E3%81%9C%E3%82%93%E3%81%9C%E3%82%93%E3%82%8F%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E4%BF%BA%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A1%E3%81%AF%E9%9B%B0%E5%9B%B2%E6%B0%97%E3%81%A7%E6%A0%AA%E3%82%92%E3%82%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B). 雰囲気で in the title of [this book](https://nextpublishing.jp/book/10979.html) is the same. 雰囲気で話す人 is someone who says plausible-sounding things that are not based on logic.

～とは何だったのか means "What was ～?" or "What was the point of (saying) ～?". So since Irido is studying hard now, this guy is wondering why he said 雰囲気で点が取れる earlier.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Also, I forgot to ask what form the verb 取れる takes. Is it spontaneous?

Comment: @JohnDavies No, it's the potential form of 取る (i.e., "*can* get").